# Why epoll is giving data from past events?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, uart

I am trying to read uart serial data from Linux.
I have 2 serial device mapped to linux file system , eg : ttys1 and ttys2.
After that open() is used to get FD's :

```
int fd1 = open("ttys1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
int fd2 = open("ttys2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
```

This calls are in object contructor and application is in idle state for example

On Running state , I want to record uart data from this devices.

I have a thread which is calling a start() method that creates an epoll and add fd1 and fd2 to epoll to monitor:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++)
{
  events[i].events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLERR | EPOLLET ;
  events[i].data.fd = (i == 0) ? fd1 : fd2;

  if(epoll_ctl(epollFD, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, events[i].data.fd, &events[i]))
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to add file descriptor to epoll\n");
     close(epollFD);
     return;
   }
   else
   {
   cout << "Succesfully added File Descriptors to ePoll" << endl;
   }
}
```

After that I have a running thread which is waiting for epoll events and read out data using epoll_wait()

My problem is that first events are with big chunk of data which I want to ignore . If usually i am getting 1-10 bytes from each uart device after each epoll wait , on first shot I get buffered data from those devices but I only want to monitor traffic after fd's were added to epoll. Any Ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `read` to read and throw away all the buffered data when your application transitions from Idle to Running?  epoll is not going to read or throw away any data for you, it only tells you when there is data to read.

Comment: What's been put in the buffer before you register a file descriptor for epolling is still there and will be the first thing you'll read when epoll triggers.  Read and discard them.

Comment: I was thinking i can make use of some flags from open() or events[i].events flags or maybe a method to clear that buffer before read